# Why mdadm --examine --scan gives two same ARRAYs?

Tags: mdadm

The following confuses me:

```
[root@mrak ~]# mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=d3f800db:26de8691:dc0caf45:0f75028b name=mrak.dex.internal:0
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=1870fd84:2234e3d4:580f7634:b0b621e7 name=mrak.dex.internal:0
```

This array is RAID10 comprising 4 Seagate Momentus XT 750GB disks. The active RAID's UUID is d3f800db:26de8691:dc0caf45:0f75028b. Can someone explain to me why am I getting the second ARRAY line?

Also, why I do not see /dev/sdb1, /dev/sde1 and /dev/sde1? Those are all partitions used to build the array, that are of type "Linux raid autodetect".

If I get details for /dev/md/0 I get:

```
[root@mrak ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md/0
/dev/md/0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri Feb  8 12:47:03 2013
     Raid Level : raid10
     Array Size : 1464886528 (1397.02 GiB 1500.04 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 732443264 (698.51 GiB 750.02 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Feb 13 09:20:54 2013
          State : clean, degraded, recovering
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 128K

 Rebuild Status : 14% complete

           Name : mrak.dex.internal:0  (local to host mrak.dex.internal)
           UUID : d3f800db:26de8691:dc0caf45:0f75028b
         Events : 151

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
       1       8       64        1      active sync   /dev/sde
       2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
       4       8       33        3      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: Can you show mdadm --examine --scan -vvvv command output ?

Comment: I can't - destroyed the array and made it again, so the mystery array disappeared. :)

Comment: I vote for close hence.